# How to denote domain and range

Tags: notation

Is there a common way to denote the domain or range of a function? I've seen things like
$ \cal{D}\left(f\right) $ and $ \cal{R}\left(f\right) $ for the domain and range, respectively, but I wasn't sure if there was a more explicit syntax for this (e.g., the way that cardinality has a specific syntax instead of just $\mathrm{card}\left(X\right)$, for instance).

I know that you alternatively mention the domain and range in the "mapping" notation of the function, e.g.:

$$
f: \cal{D} \to \cal{R}
$$

But I'm really just looking for a way to explicitly indicate the domain/range of a given function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Notations vary. You should pick something straightforward, and state it clearly up front. One common choice would be $$\operatorname{dom} f\\ \operatorname{ran} f$$

another reasonable choice might be $$\mathscr{D}(f)\\\mathscr{R}(f)$$

*Principia Mathematica* used:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately the term *range* means different things for different people.

In a function $f: \cal{D} \to \cal{R}$, we call $\cal{R}$ the [*codomain*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of $f$; it's the set where $f$ takes its values.

The [*image*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29) of $f$ is the set of values of $f$; it's a subset of the codomain, but usually smaller.

The term [*range*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_%28mathematics%29) means either *codomain* or *image*, and so is better avoided.

If you need notation, you may use $\text{dom}(f)$, $\text{codom}(f)$, $\text{im}(f)$.

Comment: I was about to type up the same response when yours popped up.  This is certainly an important distinction.  http://www.xamuel.com/range-vs-codomain/ gives some of the popular reasons.  Also important to note the use of preimage for domain, though those terms also have some conflicting use.